# How can I horizontally center navigation menu?

Tags: css

I'd like to center the navigation bar but I'm not sure which part of the code is problematic.

```
  <div align="center"><ul id="nav" class="dropdown dropdown-horizontal"><li class="hover"><a href="http://nunezmarcusstudio.com/wordpress">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a name="blank">PORTFOLIOS</a>
  <ul>
```

Comment: First, I must say that this has nothing to do with PHP. It also has nothing (or at least shouldn't) with HTML. It's CSS matters to center your div. Please, post more code and we would help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, your html is missing end div tag

more importantly, instead of , assign an id selector to your div tag and apply CSS to get the centering

for instance

```
<div id="wrapper"><ul id="nav">...</ul></div>
```

and css

```
body {width:100%;}
#wrapper {width:700px;margin:0 auto;}
```